# Python3, Tuples in a list, how to get all the values inside them

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have got tuples nested in a list.

Every tuple have 3 objects inside them.

And i have created a dictionary for the first and second object in the list and a dictionary for the first and third object in the list.

My main Problem is that I can not get the values inside the tuples in the list.

I tried a List Comprehension, Which only works for list.

I needed a way to insert the objects to the dictionary.

```
Variable = [('Bla','Blo','foo'),('Hello','Bye','Seeyou'),('Morning','Afternoon','Evening')]

Dictionary1 = {}
Dictionary2 = {}

for item in Variable:

    PreKidsVar[x[len(PreKidsVar)]
```

This is how I expected it:

```
Dictionary1 = {'Bla':'Blo','Hello':'Bye','Morning':'Afternoon'}
Dictionary2 = {'Bla':'foo','Hello':'Seeyou','Morning':'Evening'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict-comprehension` as below:

```
Dictionary1 = {i[0]:i[1] for i in Variable}
Dictionary2 = {i[0]:i[2] for i in Variable}
```

Or you can do:

```
Dictionary1 = {}
Dictionary2 = {}

for i in Variable:
  Dictionary1[i[0]] = i[1]
  Dictionary2[i[0]] = i[2]

print(Dictionary1)
print(Dictionary2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below code which uses single for loop:**

```
Variable = [('Bla','Blo','foo'),('Hello','Bye','Seeyou'),('Morning','Afternoon','Evening')]
dict1 ={}
dict2 ={}
for i in Variable:
    dict1[i[0]]=i[1]
    dict2[i[0]]=i[2]

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
```

**Result:**

```
{'Bla': 'Blo', 'Hello': 'Bye', 'Morning': 'Afternoon'}
{'Bla': 'foo', 'Hello': 'Seeyou', 'Morning': 'Evening'}
```